# html inside php inside html parsing issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having this problem

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

in this line

```
<?php ... foreach($res as $row) {echo '<input onclick="selectall('.$j.',"flow'.$row['uid'].'","hi'.$row['uid'].'")" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Update" />';} ?>
```

Output of that line

```
<input onclick="selectall(5,"flow9C2748C40A24","hi9C2748C40A24")" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Update" />
```

The problem is here i think

```
,"flow'.$row['uid'].'","hi'.$row['uid'].'"
```

because when i remove it, the problem disappear

***Appreciate any help !***

Comment: Is this inside or outside the `<?php ... ?>` tags?

Comment: @NigelRen inside `<?php ... ?>` tags

Comment: Are you encasing all of this in quotes if its inside PHP? Like this : `'<input onclick="selectall('.$j.',"flow'.$row['uid'].'","hi'.$row['uid'].'")" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Update" />'`

Comment: can you add the proper code - is this inside an `echo` statement for example?

Comment: @John yes of course, i'm using `echo 'postedcode' ;`

Comment: @RamRaider question modified please check the first code again

Comment: @RamRaider question modified again, kindly check

Comment: Can you share the code for what `$res` is?

Comment: @John i don't think that have anything to do with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of functions which should possibly help when it comes to formatting strings - namely `printf` and `sprintf` (others in this family also exist) - and these allow you to specify placeholders in the string which are substituted with the arguments provided. Using these helps simplify how the strings are `escaped`

```
printf(
    '<input type="submit" onclick="selectall( \'%1$s\', \'flow%2$s\', \'hi%2$s\' )" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" />',
    $j,
    $row['uid']
);
```